Randomly assigning number 1-11 to vector elements, without repeats?
I have a vector with 11 characters, and I want to randomly assign a number 1 through 11 to each, without repeating a number.

I tried this:
df %>% 
  group_by(numbers) %>% 
  mutate(random = sample(11,1))

However this randomized them, but with repeats.

Welcom to SO @Jessica. Please, don't share code as image, provide sample/toy data and your attempted code, so we can try to reproduce the problem and help you! Take a moment and read this post about how to make good SO questions.

You don't need to group. About sample, the problem is because you specified the sample size: 1. Try this:
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(15)

# Toy data
my_df  <- tibble(fruit = fruit[1:11], number = 1:11)

# 
new_df <- mutate(my_df, number = sample(number)) # Without the sample size!

The output:
> new_df
# A tibble: 11 × 2
   fruit        number
   <chr>         <int>
 1 apple             5
 2 apricot          10
 3 avocado           2
 4 banana            1
 5 bell pepper       6
 6 bilberry          8
 7 blackberry       11
 8 blackcurrant      3
 9 blood orange      7
10 blueberry         9
11 boysenberry       4

Created on 2024-05-30 with reprex v2.1.0
